# How to read file with okio inside commanMain module in a Kotlin Multiplatform Project?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, okio

I am trying to read/write files in the `commonMain` module.

I created a new Kotlin Multiplatform App for Android and iOS using the Android Studio Wizard. (`New -> New Project ... -> Koltin Multiplatform App`)

Then I added okio as dependency to common in the `shared/build.gradle.kts` file.

```
    sourceSets {
        val okio = "3.3.0"
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.squareup.okio:okio:$okio")
            }
        }
        ...
```

In the module commonMain I cannot access `FileSystem.SYSTEM` (`Unresolved Reference: SYSTEM`) and therefore not read or write any files.

In the module `iOSMain` and `androidMain` I can access `FileSystem.SYSTEM`. Is this expected behaviour? This would require me to write an `expected`/`actual` mapping for all okio apis. Or is there an other way?

Or do I need to configure my project differently to be able to access `FileSystem.SYSTEM` inside the `commonMain`-Module?

`shared/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        val okio = "3.3.0"
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.squareup.okio:okio:$okio")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "de.pixel.kmmpodstryout"
    compileSdk = 32
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
```

Greetings.kt in commonMain from the sample app generated by the wizard:

```
package de.pixel.kmmpodstryout

import okio.FileSystem
import okio.Path.Companion.toPath

class Greeting {
    private val platform: Platform = getPlatform()

    fun greet(): String {
        val path = "helloworld.txt".toPath()

        FileSystem.SYSTEM <--- "Unresolved Reference SYSTEM"

        return "Hello, ${platform.name} ${readFile()}!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Because SYSTEM isn't available on all platforms, I think you need to inject it into your KMP "graph" from each platform.

Comment: Super easy with an expect/actual top level function getFilesystem

Answer (score 0):

The `FileSystem.SYSTEM` is only available in the platform specific folders. To use it in commonMain you can use the expect/actual mechanism.

1. Create a FileSystemPlatform.kt in commonMain
   This contains the following code:

   `expect val fileSystem: FileSystem`
2. Create implementations for the platforms (in this case iOS and Android).
   These files are names FileSystemPlatform.ios.kt and FileSystemPlatform.android.kt. Both these files have the following content:

   `actual val fileSystem: FileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM`
3. Now you can use the `fileSystem` variable in the whole commonMain module.